# Instal memcached with php7

Tags: php, cache, caching

How can I install memcached from php.net and work it with php7+? I tried a couple of tutorials from other sites (I do not remember now) but it does not work. Can anyone help me to do this, I am quite new with Ubuntu and web development, so anything may help me.

Answer (score 1):

This is solution for you complete steps to install the memcached and php7 on Ubuntu OS:

First, You get and instal the PHP-7 and memcached:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y tmux curl wget \
    nginx \
    php7.0-fpm \
    php7.0-cli php7.0-curl php7.0-gd \
    php7.0-intl php7.0-mysql php-memcached
```

Then PHP7 is installed!

Seconds, If php-memcached was not installed, we can build it manually. (However, it's likely available to install via the php7.0-memcached package now).

If you need a newer version of the PHP-Memcached module, we can build it manually. Here's how:

```
sudo apt-get install -y php7.0-dev git pkg-config build-essential libmemcached-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libmemcached-dev libmemcached11 git build-essential

git clone https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached
cd php-memcached
git checkout php7
git pull

/usr/local/php7/bin/phpize
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/php7/bin/php-config

make
sudo make install
```

Then we need to setup PHP (CLI and FPM) to use the memcached module. Edit `/etc/php/mods-available/memcached.ini`, add:

```
; configuration for php memcached module
; priority=20
extension=memcached.so
```

Then enable it by including symlinks to that file in the FPM/CLI conf.d directories:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/php/mods-available/memcached.ini /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-memcached.ini
sudo ln -s /etc/php/mods-available/memcached.ini /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-memcached.ini
```

Reload php-fpm to include the new changes

```
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
```

And there we have it, PHP7 is installed, with Memcached support!

Comment: Why `tmux` is required it can easily be ommited and shill have phph installed!. Also memcached has its own package as well.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 18.04, you need to get php-memcached from a nonstandard repo:

```
sudo apt-get install libmemcached-tools
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
```

Then, if you hadn't done this yet:

```
sudo apt-get install php php-dev php-pear libapache2-mod-php
```

Finally:

```
sudo apt-get install php-memcached
service apache2 restart
```